# Ajax resetting my global variable

Tags: php, functions, ajax

I am wondering why I can't read the updated value of `$_TEST`. It seems that `$_TEST` is being reset with each Ajax call.

```php
// functions.php
$_TEST = 0; // the variable I want to update  with each Ajax call
if ( is_admin() ) {
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_global_val', 'get_global_val');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_global_val', 'get_global_val');
}
function get_global_val() // my Ajax function
{ 
  global $_TEST;    // the value I want to update
  echo $_TEST; // displaying 0 instead of 1
  $_TEST = 1; // update my variable
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you're making an ajax call, `$_TEST = 0;` is being evaluated again. You use the [options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) to manipulate your variable.

```
function get_global_val() 
{
   $count = get_option( 'mycount' );
   $count++; //or whatever you want to do with it
   update_option( 'mycount', $count );
   die("New value is $count");
}
```

Comment: @P-S each http request is entirely separate with no data persisted between. the moment the last byte of your page request left the server, that request was gone from memory, your new ajax request, and each subsequent request, has no access to anything you do in php unless you persist it by writing to database or file.